# Creating an IPv6 Socket failed with invalid IP - seems to get truncated

Tags: c++, sockets

I am currently learning C++ and I'm working on a library that will allow sockets to be created on Windows and Linux, supporting IPv4 and IPv6.

I've got it working fine on IPv4 but I'm having a problem with IPv6.

I've tried doing it so it binds to an IP address or binds to a specific IPV6 address but either fail.

Below is how I create a socket.

```
this->serverSocket = socket(family, socketType, 0);
        if (this->serverSocket < 0)
        {
            stringstream logstream;
            logstream << "Error opening socket. Most likely trying to bind to an ";
            logstream << "invalid IP or the port is already in use";
            bitsLibrary->writeToLog(logstream.str(), "LinuxSocket", "createSocket");
            return false;
        }

        switch (family)
        {
            case AF_INET: {
                this->serv_addr = new sockaddr();
                bzero((sockaddr*)this->serv_addr, sizeof(this->serv_addr));
                sockaddr_in *sin = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(serv_addr);
                sin->sin_family = family;
                //sin->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
                //If IP Address is NULL then set to IPADDR_ANY
                if (ipAddress.empty())
                {
                    sin->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
                }
                else
                {
                    inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &sin->sin_addr);
                }
                sin->sin_port = htons(port);
                break;
            }
            case AF_INET6: {
                this->serv_addr = new sockaddr();
                bzero((sockaddr*)this->serv_addr, sizeof(this->serv_addr));
                sockaddr_in6 *sin = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6*>(serv_addr);
                sin->sin6_family = family;
                if (ipAddress.empty())
                {
                    sin->sin6_addr = IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT;
                }
                else
                {
                    inet_pton(AF_INET6, ipAddress.c_str(), &(sin->sin6_addr));
                }
                sin->sin6_port = htons(port);
                break;
            }
            default:
                this->bitsLibrary->writeToLog("Invalid socket family. Only AF_INET or AF_INET6 is supported");
                return false;
        }
```

Below is how I then bind the socket

```
stringstream logstream;
    int result = bind(this->serverSocket, (sockaddr * )serv_addr, sizeof(*serv_addr));
    if (result < 0)
    {
        logstream << "Failed to bind socket. Error: " << strerror(result);
        throw SocketException(logstream.str().c_str());
        close(this->serverSocket);
        return false;
    }
    result = listen(this->serverSocket, this->socketPort);
    if (result < 0)
    {
        logstream << "Failed to start listening. Socket Error: " << strerror(result);
        throw SocketException(logstream.str().c_str());
    }
    logstream << "Socket " << this->socketPort << " has been successfully bound";
    this->bitsLibrary->writeToLog(logstream.str(), "LinuxSocket", "bindAndStartListening");
    return true;
```

I call the create socket function as follows

```
if (!socketManager.createSocket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 500, 50, "fe80::20c:29ff:fea0:7da8"))
```

The bind returns -1 strerror says an unknown error occurred.

The IP address that I am passing into createSocket method is `fe80::20c:29ff:fea0:7da8`.

When I run my program through strace I then get the following on the bind

```
socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
bind(4, {sa_family=AF_INET6, sin6_port=htons(500), inet_pton(AF_INET6, "fe80::", &sin6_addr), sin6_flowinfo=0, sin6_scope_id=0}, 16) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

Notice that the IP has been truncated to `fe80::`.

If I don't use an IP so it binds to anything the IP is then `::`

### Update

Below is the code I have changed for the AF_INET6 socket.

```
case AF_INET6: {
                this->serv_addr = new sockaddr_storage();
                bzero((sockaddr_in6*)this->serv_addr, sizeof(this->serv_addr));
                sockaddr_in6 *sin = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6*>(serv_addr);
                sin->sin6_family = family;
                if (ipAddress.empty())
                {
                    sin->sin6_addr = IN6ADDR_ANY_INIT;
                }
                else
                {
                    inet_pton(AF_INET6, ipAddress.c_str(), &sin->sin6_addr);
                }
                sin->sin6_port = htons(port);
                break;
}
```

I've also change this->servAddr is sockaddr_storage in the header as suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least on Windows, `sizeof(sockaddr) < sizeof(sockaddr_in6)`. When you allocate memory for `this->serv_addr`, you allocate not enough, then corrupt your heap block, and then you have bugs.

It's suggested that you use `sockaddr_storage` which is "Large enough to accommodate all supported protocol-specific address structures". Or you can allocate different structures in different cases, which shouldn't be a problem for the rest of your code.

**UPDATE 1**

There still seems to be a few mistakes in your code. You need to check all references to `this->serv_addr` and verify types/sizeof's.

-- Example 1: You `bzero()` a wrong number of bytes here - not only a wrong sizeof of wrong type, but also you do sizeof on a pointer:

```
bzero((sockaddr_in6*)this->serv_addr, sizeof(this->serv_addr));
```

Should be fixed like that:

```
sockaddr_in6 *sin = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in6*>(serv_addr);
bzero(sin, sizeof(*sin));
```

-- Example 2: You pass wrong buffer size here:

```
int result = bind(this->serverSocket, (sockaddr * )serv_addr, sizeof(*serv_addr));
```

You should remember the actual size for `this->serv_addr` at the time you allocate it and pass this size to `bind()`

Comment: Hmm, its made progress, it can bind to any address now (although can't connect to it locally via the ip6 address, only works from a remote machine, but if I specify an IP address it still shows the EINVAL in the strace when it does the bind

Comment: Update your code so I can see changes. For example, not sure if you fixed `sizeof(*serv_addr)`. Also, I suggest that you use IPPROTO_TCP in `create()` instead if 0.

Comment: what's wrong with the buffer size I'm passing into the bind, everything I've looked at online seems to match what I have, the only difference being I'm dereferencing so that its not a pointer to the struct as it expects

Comment: It must match the actual size of `serv_addr`. For IPv6, it will be `sizeof(sockaddr_in6)`. You need to remember the size of `serv_addr` when you allocate it.

Comment: OK, I've given that a try. I found something I need to set `sin6_scope_id` which I've done using `sin->sin6_scope_id = if_nametoindex("eno16777728");` so I now get `EADDRNOTAVAIL (Cannot assign requested address)`. Not sure if that's making progress or not

Comment: Not sure how IPv6 changes it, but in IPv4 you can only bind to IP's your network interfaces have. You need to check your IP address you pass to `bind()` for actually being available on your network cards.

Comment: I have one network interface, which in ifconfig shows 1 ipv4 and 1 ipv6 address, which I've copied and pasted to my function so the IP should be available

Comment: Although its not binding to a specific IPv6 address, the rest of it is working, it now binds locally and on any interface. I think this other problem with binding to the ipv6 interface should be in another post, but what you've suggested works for the rest of the issue. Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you should minify your code down to just a few lines that demonstrate `socket()` and `bind()` to IPv6 address. If it still fails to bind, it would indeed be reasonable to put another question.